# Asking Company to Purchase a Lab Notebook

Tags: company-norms

This is probably a ridiculous question one way or the other but I don't know the answer so I thought I'd ask. Is it reasonable to ask my company (a small startup) to purchase a lab notebook for my work?

A few things working in favor:

1. I'll only use it for work related tasks
2. I believe the confidentiality paperwork I signed on my first day says that the company owns everything I work on e.g. they would own the content of the lab notebook anyways.

Against:

1. Only I personally would be using the lab notebook.

Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but do you mean a notebook computer (a la ChromeBook) for your lab? Or a paper notebook to hand write things in?

Comment: If we're talking about stationery, you're definitely overthinking this. If we're talking about a laptop, and you have a decent argument for needing it, you're also overthinking it. Just ask, the worst they can say is no.

Comment: This definitely needs a confirmation to distinguish whether OP means a notebook laptop or a paper notebook.

Comment: Whether he means a notebook computer or an actual notebook only effects the price of the item; conceptually it's still the same question with the same answer.  If you need it to do your job, it's absolutely reasonable to ask them to buy it.  If you don't actually need it to do your job, but you can make a case for it benefiting the company in some way, it's also reasonable to diplomatically suggest the idea.

Answer (score 4):

(You might be overthinking here)

Buying and using notebooks is part of the day to day operations of a company.

Ask your office administrator and submit a purchase order.

Comment: Heck, they probably have a stack sitting in the supply cabinet...